# Probablity generated function of a sum of random

Tags: probability

The question I am trying to solve is.
Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be independent random variabels. $E[X_k]=m^k$
$m\neq 1, k = 1,2,3...$
$N \in Po(\lambda), S_N = X_1+X_2+...+X_N$
I need to show that:
$E[S_N]=\frac{m}{m-1}(e^{\lambda(m-1)}-1)$

What I have tried is using a probabilty generating function for a sum of r.v:s and then taking the derivative of that expression and got the asked answer, but...
This is what i have gotten using the convolution formula for a pgf.
$g_{S_N}(t) = g_N(\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}g_j(t))$
Where $g_N(t)$ is the pgf of for the poisson distrubuted variabel. $g_j(t)$ is for the others.

Second step would be to take the derivate of $g_{s_N}(t)$ but I dont think that is correct. Becasue I get a large expression and I don't actaully know the pgf function for all of the variabels.

So hoppefully someone can tell me where I am thinking wrong.

Comment: I assume by "$N\in Po(\lambda)$" you mean that $N$ has Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$?

Comment: You probably assume that $N$ is independent of $(X_n)$, otherwise the result does not hold (but the hypothesis that $(X_n)$ is independent is irrelevant, and not needed). Then the result follows from the pointwise identity $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n\mathbf 1_{N\geqslant n}$$

Comment: @Math1000 yes that is how the text bok writes  it.

Answer (score 1):

The method of composing generating functions only works when the $X_n$ are i.i.d. Instead, we can use the law of total expectation:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[S_N] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb E[S_N\mid N=n] \mathbb P(N=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n m^k \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\\
&= \frac m{m-1}e^{-\lambda}\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\lambda m)^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\right)\\
&=\frac m{m-1} e^{-\lambda}\left(e^{\lambda m}-e^{\lambda} \right)\\
&=\frac m{m-1} \left(e^{\lambda(m-1)}-1 \right).
\end{align}